# Courier API integration not working on woocommerce orders page

Tags: php, api, woocommerce

Hi have created a API with the following courier API doc -https://documenter.getpostman.com/view/2869886/T1LLDTRq#0eced6d0-4b19-4ad0-9430-a984ff507539

A button to download a waybill is supposed to appear on the orders page the weird thing is that it was working a few weeks ago not sure why it's not working?

Dawnwing Services
The Dawnwing RESTful JSON API is an API that can be used by external programs to speak to our system. It can, amongst other things, create waybills, Create Parcels, Create tracking And book collections.

Base URL:

UAT https://swatws.dawnwing.co.za/dwwebservices/v2/uat/api/

LIVE https://swatws.dawnwing.co.za/dwwebservices/v2/live/api/

```
<?php


/***********************************thankyou page generate order url*********************************************/

add_action('woocommerce_order_status_shipped', 'wdm_send_order_to_ext');
function wdm_send_order_to_ext( $order_id ){
    // get order object and order details
    $order = new WC_Order( $order_id ); 
    $email = $order->billing_email;
    $phone = $order->billing_phone;
    $shipping_type = (array)$order->get_shipping_method();
    $order_number = $order->order_number;
    if(!empty( $order->get_items( 'shipping' ))){
        $shipping_method_instance_id ='';
        foreach( $order->get_items( 'shipping' ) as $item_id => $shipping_item_obj ){
            $shipping_method_instance_id .= $shipping_item_obj->get_instance_id(); 
        }
    }
    $instance_id = $shipping_method_instance_id;
    if( $instance_id == 1 )
    {
    $_shipping_type = "ONX";
    }
    else{
    $_shipping_type = "ECON";
    }
    
    $shipping_cost = $order->get_total_shipping();

    // set the address fields//
    $user_id = $order->user_id;
    $address_fields = array('country',
        'title',
        'first_name',
        'last_name',
        'company',
        'address_1',
        'address_2',
        'address_3',
        'address_4',
        'city',
        'state',
        'postcode');

    $address = array();
    if(is_array($address_fields)){
        foreach($address_fields as $field){
            $address['billing_'.$field] = get_user_meta( $user_id, 'billing_'.$field, true );
            $address['shipping_'.$field] = get_user_meta( $user_id, 'shipping_'.$field, true );
        }
    }
    
  
    // get product details//
    $items = $order->get_items();
    
    $item_name = array();
    $item_qty = array();
    $item_price = array();
    $item_sku = array();
        
    foreach( $items as $key => $item){
        $item_name[] = $item['name'];
        $item_qty[] = $item['qty'];
        $item_price[] = $item['line_total'];
        
        $item_id = $item['product_id'];
        $product = new WC_Product($item_id);
        $item_sku[] = $product->get_sku();
    }
    
$customer_note = $order->get_customer_note();
    $transaction_key = get_post_meta( $order_number, '_transaction_id', true );
    $transaction_key = empty($transaction_key) ? $_GET['key']  : $transaction_key;
    
    // set the username and password//
    $api_username = 'test';
    $api_password = 'test';
 // to test out the API, set $api_mode as ‘sandbox’//
 
     // production URL example//
    
 
        // setup the data which has to be sent//
            
        $datawaybill =  [
            "waybillNo"=> $order_number,
            "sendAccNo"=> "CPT3685",
            "sendSite"=> "CPT3685ONL",
            "sendCompany"=> "LITTLE BRAND BOX",
            "sendAdd1"=> "101 Bree Castle House",
            "sendAdd2"=> "68 Bree Street",
            "sendAdd3"=> "",
            "sendAdd4"=> "Cape Town",
            "sendAdd5"=> "8000",
            "sendContactPerson"=> "Zak",
            "sendHomeTel"=> null,
            "sendWorkTel"=> "0214236868",
            "sendCell"=> null,
            "recCompany"=> "",
            "recAdd1"=> $order->get_shipping_address_1(),
            "recAdd2"=> $order->get_shipping_address_2(),
            "recAdd3"=> $order->get_shipping_city(),
            "recAdd4"=> $order->get_shipping_state(),
            "recAdd5"=> $order->get_shipping_postcode(),
            "recAdd7"=> $company,
            "recContactPerson"=> $order->get_shipping_first_name().' '.$order->get_shipping_last_name(),
            "recHomeTel"=> "",
            "recWorkTel"=> $phone,
            "recCell"=> $phone,
            "specialInstructions"=> $order->get_customer_note(),
            "serviceType"=> $_shipping_type,
            "totQTY"=> 1,
            "totMass"=> 1,
            "insurance"=> false,
            "insuranceValue"=> 0,
            "customerRef"=> $order_number,
            "storeCode"=> "LBB",
            "securityStamp"=> null,
            "requiredDocs"=> [],
            "waybillInstructions"=> [],
            "instructionCode"=> "",
            "isSecureDelivery"=> false,
            "verificationNumbers"=> null,
            "generateSecurePin"=> false,
            "collectionNo"=> null,
            "invoiceRef"=> null,
            "parcels"=> [
            [
            "waybillNo"=> $order_number,
            "length"=> 26,
            "height"=> 5,
            "width"=> 23,
            "mass"=> 1,
            "parcelDescription"=> "HAIR HEALTH PRODUCTS",
            "parcelNo"=> $order_number . "_1",
            "parcelCount"=> 1
            ]
            ],
            "completeWaybillAfterSave"=> true
            ];

          // send API request via cURL
           $ch = curl_init();

           // set the complete URL, to process the order on the external system. Let’s consider http ->//example.com/buyitem.php is the URL, which invokes the API //
           curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://swatws.dawnwing.co.za/dwwebservices/V2/live/api/waybill');
           curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
           curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($datawaybill));
           curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
           curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json','Content-Type: application/json'));
           $response = curl_exec ($ch);
       
           curl_close ($ch);
        
           // the handle response    
           if (strpos($response,'ERROR') !== false) {
               print_r('eror');
       } else {   
           $datacompletewaybill = array(
           'waybillNo' => $order_number,
               'storeCode' => "LBB",
               'securityStamp' => '',
               'generateLabel' => true,
           );
   
              // send API request via cURL
       $ch = curl_init();
   
       // set the complete URL, to process the order on the external system. Let’s consider http ->//example.com/buyitem.php is the URL, which invokes the API //
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://swatws.dawnwing.co.za/dwwebservices/V2/live/api/waybill/completewaybill');
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($datacompletewaybill));
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json','Content-Type: application/json') );
       $response = curl_exec ($ch);
       
       curl_close ($ch);
               $response_array = json_decode($response);
               if(!empty($response_array)):
               update_post_meta($order_id, 'my_field_order_url', $response_array->data[0] );
               
               endif;
   }
   
   }
   
   
   /**
    * Display field value on the order edit page
    */
   add_action( 'woocommerce_admin_order_data_after_billing_address', 'my_custom_checkout_field_display_admin_order_meta', 10, 1 );
   function my_custom_checkout_field_display_admin_order_meta( $order ){
       $order_id = method_exists( $order, 'get_id' ) ? $order->get_id() : $order->id;
       if($order->get_status() == 'shipped' || $order->get_status() == 'completed' ):
       echo '<p class="my_field_order_url" style="display:none;">' . get_post_meta( $order_id, 'my_field_order_url', true ) . '</p>';
       endif; ?>
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    var htmls = jQuery('p.my_field_order_url').html();
    var lengths = jQuery('p.my_field_order_url').length;
    if (htmls !== '' && lengths > 0) {
        jQuery('<div id="yith-order-traking-url" class="postbox"><div class="inside"><a class="wayb" href="' +
            htmls + '" target="_blank">Download Waybill</a></div></div>').insertAfter(
            '#yith-order-tracking-information');
    }
    jQuery('div#postcustomstuff table tbody tr td').each(function() {
        if (jQuery(this).find('input').val() === 'my_field_order_url') {
            jQuery(this).remove();
        }
        if (jQuery(this).find('textarea').val() ===
            '<?=get_post_meta( $order_id, 'my_field_order_url', true )?>') {
            jQuery(this).remove();
        }
    });
});
</script>
   <style>
       a.wayb {
       background: orange;
       float: left;
       margin: 0px !important;
       padding: 10px;
       width: 100%;
       text-align: center;
       color: white;
       text-decoration: none;
       font-size: 16px;
   }
   
   
   div#yith-order-traking-url .inside {
   
       height: 42px;
       margin: 0px;
       padding: 0px !important;
       border: 9ox !important;
       width: 100% !important;
   }
   
   </style>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that in your question you wrote `https://swatws.dawnwing.co.za/dwwebservices/v2/live/api/` but in your code you use:

- `http://swatws.dawnwing.co.za/dwwebservices/V2/live/api/waybill` *(not https)*
- `http://swatws.dawnwing.co.za/dwwebservices/V2/live/api/waybill/completewaybill` *(not https)*

Also you have set two variables with user and password (you shouldn't publish them).
**If HTTP requests require authentication**, see here:

Basic authentication:

- [How do I make a request using HTTP basic authentication with PHP curl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2140419/how-do-i-make-a-request-using-http-basic-authentication-with-php-curl)
- [How to use basic authorization in PHP curl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20064271/how-to-use-basic-authorization-in-php-curl)
- [Sending auth in headers php curl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13187462/sending-auth-in-headers-php-curl)

Bearer authentication:

- [Correct way to set Bearer token with CURL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30426047/correct-way-to-set-bearer-token-with-curl)
- [php how to use bearer token in curl get request header?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44236346/php-how-to-use-bearer-token-in-curl-get-request-header)

Comment: https://documenter.getpostman.com/view/2869886/T1LLDTRq#b151f069-94d5-457b-b3d1-7a4230ad0965 - in this doc it uses that end point I'm trying to create a waybill from the API is there any alternative ways?

Comment: I have integrated my answer. You need Bearer authentication (for more information see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Authentication#authentication_schemes)).